# linux Scp no realiza copia a server desde el cron

Tags: linux, centos7, cron

buen dia a todos..

Trabajo con centos 7, y tengo el siguiente problema a ver si alguien mas sabe que pueda estar pasando. Tengo un script, que realiza un respaldo de un esquema de una instancia de oracle, y esto genera en el server una serie de archivos con extension DMP. Luego, a traves de un **scp**, y una **relacion de confianza establecida**, se hace una copia de dichos archivos a otro server. 
El script **funciona correctamente** **cuando lo ejecuto desde un terminal**, pero deja de hacer la copia cuando dejo esto programado en el **cron** **del mismo usuario**. La relacion de confianza entre los servers esta establecida para el usuario oracle, y para el usuario root. El script lo he probado tanto con el usuario oracle y con root desde el terminal, y en ambos casos funciona correctamente la copia del archivo con el scp

Aca una copia del script (**la parte del export de los datos funciona bien**, solo falla el **scp**)

```html
cat expdp_esquema.sh
#!/bin/bash
#Parametro 1 : Instancia (sin el nodo)
#Parametro 2 : Esquema o esquemas separados por (,)
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
echo "Debe indicar instancia";
exit 1;
else
export INSTANCIA=$1 #tomamos del parametro de entrada la instancia a respaldar
fi
if [ -z "$2" ]; then
echo "Debe indicar esquema a respaldar";
exit 1;
else
export ESQUEMA=$2 #tomamos del parametro de entrada la esquema a respaldar
fi
Nodo=1 // esto es porque solo se respalda la info desde el nodo 1 del cluster
export ORACLE_SID=$INSTANCIA$Nodo
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1
export FechaRespaldo=`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`
if [[ $2 == *","* ]]; then
export NombreArch=$INSTANCIA'_'$FechaRespaldo
else
export NombreArch=$INSTANCIA'_'$ESQUEMA'_'$FechaRespaldo
fi
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/expdp USERID= \"/ as sysdba\" DIRECTORY=DATA_PUMP_DIR SCHEMAS=$ESQUEMA filesize=2G job_name=job_Res_$INSTANCIA'_'$FechaRespaldo DUMPFILE=$NombreArch'_%U'.dmp LOGFILE=$NombreArch.log PARALLEL=4 CLUSTER=N
#obtiene la ruta del directorio de datapump DATA_PUMP_DIR
RutaDataPump=`sqlplus -L -s / as sysdba <<EOF
set pages 0 feed off heading off echo off verify off termout off
select directory_path from dba_directories where directory_name = 'DATA_PUMP_DIR';
exit
EOF`
#los archivos a generar
export Arch_dmp=$RutaDataPump$NombreArch'*.dmp'
export Arch_log=$RutaDataPump$NombreArch'.log'
#la copia al server ovs (esto es lo que esta fallando desde el CRON)
scp $Arch_dmp root@10.13.0.66:/media/storage/datapump/prod/$INSTANCIA/.
scp $Arch_log root@10.13.0.66:/media/storage/datapump/prod/$INSTANCIA/.
#fin del script
```

el cron es asi (se ejecuta a diario a las 00:00)

```html
00 00 * * * nohup time sh /home/oracle/scripts/Respaldos/DataPump/expdp_esquema.sh externos pasi >> /home/oracle/scripts/Respaldos/DataPump/log/externos_pasi.out 2>&1
```

Como comentaba antes, esto funciona al 100% sin problemas desde un terminal, tanto con el usuario oracle como con el usuario root. Pero al ejecutarse desde el cron, **la parte del scp no se realiza**.

Alguna idea de porque falla cuando lo ejecuta el sistema desde el cron del usuario oracle?

Saludos y gracias.

Comment: ¿Puedes modificar el script y que la salida del SCP se vuelque a un fichero de  texto? Tambien agregar `-vvv` al SCP de manera que podamos tener algo más de información https://linux.die.net/man/1/scp

Comment: ya encontre la respuesta. mira mas abajo ahi lo explico. gracias

Answer (score 2):

Ya encontre la respuesta. el ambiente del cron, no tiene todas las características que tiene una consola, de hecho, en el cron, no se ejecuta el archivo .bash_profile, lo cual provoca que funciones tan simples como la copia de archivos no se puedan llevar a cabo por falta de variables de ambiente.
la solución fue bastante simple, invocar en el script el .bash_profile, así todo funciona como en la consola.
Espero esto le sirva a alguien mas con el mismo problema
Saludos y gracias a los que comentaron.

Answer (score 1):

se necesita crear una relacion de confianza entre ambos servidores.

y ejecutar al principio del script:

```
# ubuntu / oracle linux / hp_ux
source ~/.bash_profile
# centos / red hat / aix
source ~/.profile
```

esto cargara las variables de ambiente del usuario root